# The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: maven, cmd, jmeter, system-variable

I'm getting this error when trying to run this jmeter sentence from a maven project in java.

```
jmeter -g  DIRECTORY -o DIRECTORY
```

When I run it in cmd it works perfectly but when I try to run it using this:

```
processBuilder.command("cmd.exe","/c","jmeter -g  DIRECTORY -o DIRECTORY");
    processBuilder.directory(new File("C:\\apache-jmeter-5.3\\bin"));
    try {

      Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

It says The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

When I run the command echo %JMETER_HOME% it returns C:\apache-jmeter-5.3

What I found weird is that in other PC it all works fine and that one doesn't have the JMETER_HOME variable defined, so I tried deleting the variable from this PC but it won't delete, it's not appearing in the system variables window but when I echo it's there.

What is going on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want us to guess what is the difference between one your PC and the other one without providing any information apart from incomplete code?

I can only state that I cannot reproduce your issue and yes, I don't have `JMETER_HOME` variable set anywhere.

If you're using Maven maybe it worth considering looking at [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) which can automatically download JMeter, run the test and [generate the HTML reporting dashboard](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Generating-Reports).

Also be informed that [according to JMeter Best Practices you're supposed to use the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) (or whatever is the latest version of JMeter available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue of JMETER_HOME not been set, even though I tried setting that Env variable.
I was tying to launch the Jmeter on the Virtual system (VM) using command prompt, and didn't succeed.
I able to solve it by running the command prompt as **admin** and launching Jemter, it worked fine.

Note: make sure you have the set the Env. PATH set to the bin folder of Jmeter